# Using fact that limit must be indeterminate in a proof

Tags: calculus, limits

If I know that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {f(x)-g(x)}{x}=0$$

can I then conclude that this fraction must be of indeterminate form and that

$\lim_{x\to 0} {f(x)-g(x)}=0 $  ?

If this is true how can I prove this? I know I can't use the quotient rule because the denominator is zero. Also, I cant use the product rule because $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {1}{x}=DNE$$

If this is not true, is there a similar result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {f(x)-g(x)}{x}$$ exists and is equal to $0$, and you know that $$\lim_{x\to 0} x$$ exists and is equal to $0$. Hence by the product rule for limits, you can conclude that $$\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot\left(\frac {f(x)-g(x)}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-g(x))$$ exists and is equal to $$\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {f(x)-g(x)}{x}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to 0} x\right)=0\cdot 0 = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you! This is quite helpful!